# Histogram (plotting count data)

Tags: r, histogram

I want to plot histogram with 6 classes. I tried without success.

my data :

```
      1  2  4  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 #1st row score
      1  1  2  2  1  4  2  3  3  2  1  3  3  2 #2d frequency (number of persons how obtained this score )
```

Comment: What are your six classes?

Comment: Also it's helpful to post the code that you actually tried.

Comment: [1,4[;[4,6[;[6,9[;[9,11[;[11,14[;[14,16[

Comment: > MoyBAC
 [1]  1  2  4  4  6  6  7  8  8  8  8  9  9 10 10 10 11 11 11 12 12 13 14 14 14 15 15 15 16 16
> hist(MoyBAC,classes,ylim=c(0,16), col =c("chocolate1","chartreuse3","cadetblue2","darkolivegreen3","darkorange1","darkseagreen4") ,labels=T,main="Histogramme variable MoyBAC",xlab="Moyenne au Bac",ylab="effectifs")

Comment: It's better to edit your original question, than add comments with more info.

Answer (score 1):

Histograms are appropriate for estimating the density of continuous random variables. It soulds like you just want to plot counts for discrete observations. That can be done with a bar chart. You can make that with

```
group<-c(1,2,4,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
counts<-c(1,1,2,2,1,4,2,3,3,2,1,3,3,2)

barplot(counts, names.arg=group)
```

assuming i've understood your data correctly.

Comment: Thank you for your help I mean continuous random variables, not discrete variables. that's concern scores obtained ( 1st row) and number of persons who obtained this score ( frequency? effectives sorry for my bad english).